# Jackson XML custom field deserializer

Tags: java, xml, jackson

When using Jackson for JSON processing I extended `JsonDeserializer<T>` and was able to handle custom deserialization. Is there a similar thing for processing XML with Jackson?

```
import java.util.List;

public class Something {

    private int iinteger;

    private String sstring;

    private List<String> sarray;

    public Something(int iinteger, String sstring, List<String> sarray) {
        this.iinteger = iinteger;
        this.sstring = sstring;
        this.sarray = sarray;
    }

    public Shit() {
    }

    public int getIinteger() {
        return iinteger;
    }

    public void setIinteger(int iinteger) {
        this.iinteger = iinteger;
    }

    public String getSstring() {
        return sstring;
    }

    public void setSstring(String sstring) {
        this.sstring = sstring;
    }

    public List<String> getSarray() {
        return sarray;
    }

    public void setSarray(List<String> dumb) {
        this.sarray = dumb;
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Something xmlns="">
    <iinteger>23</iinteger>
    <sstring>hey</sstring>
    <sarray >abc abd abv</sarray >
</Something>
```

Comment: Quite broad! Tell us some more about your code and so on...

Comment: If my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33651342/1426227) solved your issues, please accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Besides JSON, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) also [de/serializes from/to XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml).

You'll need the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition to [standard Jackson annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) and optional [JAXB annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-frame.html) ([`javax.xml.bind.annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-frame.html)), Jackson provides some [XML-specific annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki/Jackson-XML-annotations).

Consider the following POJO as example:

```
public class Simple {
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 2;
}
```

You can serialize it to XML using:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new Simple());
```

The result is:

```
<Simple>
    <x>1</x>
    <y>2</y>
</Simple>
```

To deserialize:

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Simple value = xmlMapper.readValue("<Simple><x>1</x><y>2</y></Simple>", Simple.class);
```

Comment: And you can also use custom serializers with it. There are some limitations for XML output which make writing custom handlers more challenging, so use of annotations and configuration are preferred, but for simple output writing a custom serializer that works for XML format is easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [JAXB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding).

[Intro to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)

The reference implementation is called [Project Kenai](https://jaxb.java.net/).
It's part of Metro (JAX-WS reference implementation), but it can be used standalone.